# VirtualBox - what is the keys combination to show the Menu Bar?

Tags: keyboard, virtualbox

For `VirtualBox` when is applied mostly the *Full-screen mode* approach. Having Windows as Host, with the  <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> or <kbd>Host</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> keys combination is possible show through a popup the Menu Bar

Therefore: What is the equivalent keys combination for MacOS to show the same Menu Bar?. It mostly because does not exist the <kbd>Home</kbd> key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The popup menu, referred to in the OP's question, is shown below. Here, the guest operating system is Windows 11 Pro and is in **full-screen** mode. With exception of "VirtualBox VM" and "Window", the popup is the same as what would appear on the menu bar.

[image]

You can view or change the key combination assigned to this popup menu. From VirtualBox Preferences, select Input, then select the Virtual Machine tab. Scroll down until you reach "Popup Menu" in the Name column of the table, as shown below.

[image: Preferences]

The image above shows the "Popup Menu" is assigned to the key combination "Host+↖", where the "↖" symbol represents the Home key. The "Host" can be viewed or changed by scrolling to the top of the table, as shown below.

[image]

The image above shows the "Host Key Combination" is assigned to the single key "Left ⌘", where the "⌘" symbol represents the Command key. (In this case, the Command key on the left of the space bar.)

**Since your keyboard does not have a Home key, you would need to substitute "Host+fn+←" for "Host+↖", where the letters "fn" represents the Function key and the symbol "←" represents the Left key.**

In other words, if you were using the Apple Wireless Keyboard A1314 shown in the next section, then you would to need use the key combination <kbd>⌘
command</kbd>+
<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>, where the <kbd>⌘
command</kbd> key would be the one to the left of the space bar.

> Note: When the popup shown below appears, the current *Host* key will be correctly displayed. However, if you have changed the "Popup Menu" shortcut from the default of "Host+↖", the change will not be shown in the popup. In other words, the pop with show **Host+Home** regardless of what the shortcut really is.

[image]

---

### Relationship between Apple Symbols and Apple Keyboards

Below is an example of two US English Apple keyboards. The first has a numeric keypad and the second does not.

Apple Wired Keyboard A1243
[image: A1243]
Apple Wireless Keyboard A1314
[image: Apple® Wireless Keyboard]

The table below show the relationship between various symbols used by Apple and the associated key or key combination.

| Name | Symbol | Apple Wired Keyboard A1243 (With Numeric Keypad)† | Apple Wireless Keyboard A1314 (No Numeric Keypad |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Function |  | <kbd>fn</kbd> | <kbd>fn</kbd> |
| Command | ⌘ or  | <kbd>command ⌘</kbd> or <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> | <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> |
| Option | ⌥ | <kbd>alt option</kbd> | <kbd>alt option</kbd> |
| Control | ⌃ | <kbd>control</kbd> | <kbd>control</kbd> |
| Shift | ⇧ | <kbd>shift</kbd> | <kbd>shift</kbd> |
| Caps Lock | ⇪ | <kbd>caps lock</kbd> | <kbd>caps lock</kbd> |
| Left | ← | <kbd>◀</kbd> | <kbd>◀</kbd> |
| Right | → | <kbd>▶</kbd> | <kbd>▶</kbd> |
| Up | ↑ | <kbd>▲</kbd> | <kbd>▲</kbd> |
| Down | ↓ | <kbd>▼</kbd> | <kbd>▼</kbd> |
| Tab | ⇥ | <kbd>tab</kbd> | <kbd>tab</kbd> |
| Backtab | ⇤ | <kbd>shift</kbd>+ <kbd>tab</kbd> | <kbd>shift</kbd>+ <kbd>tab</kbd> |
| Return | ↩ | <kbd>return</kbd> | <kbd>enter return</kbd> |
| Enter | ⌤ | <kbd>enter</kbd> | <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>enter return</kbd> |
| Delete | ⌫ | <kbd>delete</kbd> | <kbd>delete</kbd> |
| Delete Foward | ⌦ | <kbd>delete ⌦</kbd> | <kbd>fn</kbd>+ <kbd>delete</kbd> |
| Page Up | ⇞ | <kbd>page up</kbd> | <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>▲</kbd> |
| Page Down | ⇟ | <kbd>page down</kbd> | <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>▼</kbd> |
| Home | ↖ | <kbd>home</kbd> | <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>◀</kbd> |
| End | ↘ | <kbd>end</kbd> | <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>▶</kbd> |
| Clear | ⌧ | <kbd>clear</kbd> |  |
| Space | ␣ |  |  |
| Escape | ⎋ | <kbd>esc</kbd> | <kbd>esc</kbd> |
| Eject | ⏏ | <kbd>⏏</kbd> | <kbd>⏏</kbd> |

† Key combinations involving the <kbd>fn</kbd> key have been omitted for this keyboard.

---

### Suggest Use of the Accessibility Keyboard

You can use the Accessibility Keyboard to determine the key combinations involving the Function key. Below is an image of the Accessibility Keyboard.

[image: original]

When pressing down on the Function key on my keyboard, this Accessibility Keyboard changed to the image shown below.

[image: fn pressed]

In the case of the OP's question, the <kbd>◀</kbd> key changed to the <kbd>↖</kbd> key, which indicates the OP needs to substitute "Host+fn+←" for "Host+↖".

---

### References

- [Making Sense of Mac Keyboard Symbols](https://osxdaily.com/2012/03/27/making-sense-of-mac-keyboard-symbols/)
- [Mac Keyboard Symbols.md](https://gist.github.com/jlyonsmith/6992156f18c423fd1c5af068aa311fb5)

This answer was tested using VirtualBox Version 6.1.34 r150636 (Qt5.6.3) installed on a 2013 iMac with macOS Catalina 10.15.7.

Comment: Just curious, why `↖` was defined? ... it does not appear in the keyboard ...

Comment: There are references such as [here](https://osxdaily.com/2012/03/27/making-sense-of-mac-keyboard-symbols/) and [here](https://gist.github.com/jlyonsmith/6992156f18c423fd1c5af068aa311fb5) which show this is what Apple uses to represent the home key.

Comment: Thanks for both links, sadly both show what is the Home's icon, but they don't indicate what is the key in the keyboard. For the audience it is `fn` + `left` - it is indicated at [The “Home” & “End” Button Equivalents on Mac Keyboards](https://osxdaily.com/2015/06/17/home-end-button-mac-keyboard-functions/) - so there is no need to edit the default configuration in VirtualBox